# Cisco bgp disables network routing for local network

Tags: cisco, routing

We have a situation where users are unable to access servers on network `192.168.140.0/24`.

When I examine our bgp network routes, I notice the following:

```
network_router#show ip bgp | inc 192.168.140
Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 192.168.140.0    0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
```

What does the next hop `0.0.0.0` mean? Also why the metric is set to 0?

Comment: You have asked several question that have good answers that you have not accepted. A question keeps popping up forever unless you accept an answer for the question. Please accept any answers that have answered your questions.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The next hop 0.0.0.0 means that the route is originated from this router - *i.e.*, this is the router that is sourcing this route.  The metric (or multi exit discriminator) is set to 0 by default.

That information probably doesn't help you troubleshoot your problem.  If you include a diagram of your network, we will be better able to help you.

Comment: `show ip route 192.168.140.0` output may help as well.

Answer (score -3):

Next hop 0.0.0.0/0 means that traffic to this subnet is using the default route. Anytime you see 0.0.0.0/0 it is a default route.

Default routes are a way of telling the router that if there is no specific route for a given destination then send it this in this direction.

The previous answer that 0.0.0.0/0 means it is originated from this router is incorrect, however having a metric of 0 implies that it is originated locally.

Comment: in the context of the BGP table, you are 100% incorrect.